# Can't run Haralick texture process on Orfeo ToolBox on QGIS

Tags: otb-applications, texture

I have tried to run **Haralick** texture extraction on **Orfeo**, and this error is returned:

Algoritmo Haralick Texture Extraction comenzando...

```
> C:\OTB\OTB\bin\otbcli_HaralickTextureExtraction
> -in "C:\Users\Xochitl\Desktop\Clasificación supervisada\Sentinel2A_VTC\1\S2A_MSIL1C_20170223T165311_N0204_R026_T14QPF_20170223T165747.SAFE\GRANULE\L1C_T14QPF_A008746_20170223T165747\IMG_DATA\T14QPF_20170223T165311_B03.jp2"
> -channel 1
> -ram 128
> -parameters.xrad 2
> -parameters.yrad 2
> -parameters.xoff 1
> -parameters.yoff 1
> -parameters.min 0
> -parameters.max 255
> -parameters.nbbin 8
> -texture simple
> -out "C:/Users/Xochitl/Desktop/haralick.tif"

**'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 93: ordinal not in range(128) See log for more details**
```

Any ideas of how I can solve this?

Comment: Probably the accent in the path ("...Clasificación") is causing problem?`Try to rename it if possible.